# ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row with update

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, ora-01427

I have an update statement, at first it worked with some data, but after a while I've been having issues with some regiters  , I got the following error: 
**ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row** . I thought it was the IN because the query might return repeated IDs, so I put a DISTINCT but I kept getting the same error, does anyone have any idea what could it be?

The query below:

```
 UPDATE 
        TABLE_DETAIL DET 
    SET 
        DET.ACCEPTED=?,
        DET.VALUE_ACCEPTED=(SELECT RES.VALUE FROM TABLE_RES RES WHERE RES.MYT=DET.MYT AND RES.RAD=DET.RAD AND RES.ITEM=DET.ITEM), 
    WHERE 
        DET.ID 
    IN (
        SELECT 
            DISTINCT DET_I.ID
            FROM TABLE_DETAIL DET_I, TABLE_RES RES_I, TABLE_REC REC 
            WHERE 
                DET_I.MYT = ? 
            AND 
                REC.TEMP 
                NOT IN (
                    SELECT DISTINCT TEMP 
                    FROM 
                    TABLE_IMAGES WHERE CODE=?) 
            AND RES_I.USER = ? 
        )
```

Comment: It's the `DET.VALUE_ACCEPTED=(SELECT RES.VALUE FROM...` sub-query that causes trouble.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `SELECT DISTINCT` with `IN`.

The proximal cause of your problem is this code:

```
    DET.VALUE_ACCEPTED = (SELECT RES.VALUE FROM TABLE_RES RES WHERE RES.MYT=DET.MYT AND RES.RAD=DET.RAD AND RES.ITEM=DET.ITEM),
```

It isn't really possible to say how to fix it.  The error code seems pretty clear:  More than one row is returned by this query.

You can add `WHERE rownum = 1` if you want an arbitrary value.  Or an aggregation function in the `SELECT`.

Comment: I checked this, I queried that select using the real values and I get only one row, the IN I put the DISTINCT returns two values, and with that I used it to query that select in the update and it's only one row

Comment: @Alex . . . Add `and rownum = 1` to the subquery and see if the problem goes away.